# Read File Names in directory and subdirectory

Tags: file, batch-file

I have scenario where I need to find out all `.csv` file in current directory and sub directory and execute below command where `.csv` file name will be replaced dynamically which will convert in `.txt` (From Comma delimited to tab delimited file).

I have `convertme.vbs` file which takes from file and to file name as parameter which converts file but not sure how to achieve for all files in directory and sub directory.

Below is sample command I need to execute in batch file but need batch code which will read file names and plug into below command.
`cscript convertme.vbs  From_CSV_FileName.csv  From_CSV_FileName.txt`

Comment: Look at using the `FOR /R` command.  But not sure why you just don't do this all within your vbscript.

Comment: Thanks...I included in vbs file itself. It is much easier since I do not know much dos batch programming.

Comment: Easier if you are familiar with Vbscript but is a lot more code then using a batch-file. Would literally be one line of code with a batch file: `FOR /R %%G in (*.csv) do cscript //nologo convertme.vbs "%%~G" "%%~dpnG.txt"` Recursion into subfolders using vbscript is about 15 more lines of code.

Comment: Squashman - You are god. I have never knew how to write statement what you wrote but it did the trick in one like. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

> **convertall.bat**
>
> ```
> FOR /R %%G in (*.csv) do cscript //nologo convertme.vbs "%%~G" "%%~dpnG.txt"
> ```